# Encrypt message for sending over non secure network

Tags: python, bash, cryptography, openssl

wRecently needed to swap keys with a colleague on the other side of the country.

This script encrypts a file using the other persons public key that is stored on github. It outputs a script that will re-generate the original message (if you have the private key).

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Usage:
#   ./crypt <GitHub User> <File To Encrypt>
#
# 1) Github User
# 2) File to be encrypted

#
# Requires:
#   On the creators end:
#       curl
#       python
#       python pyasn1  (sudo easy_install pyasn1)
#       base64
#       openssl
#
#   On the receivers end
#       base64
#       openssl

#
# Get the users public Key
curl -s -o /tmp/ssh.pub https://github.com/${1}.keys

#
# ssh-keygen -f /tmp/ssh.pub -e -m PKCS8  # > /tmp/pem.pub
#
# The following is required because ssh-keygen -m PKCS8 has
# been removed from the Mac. The following python script
# performs the same operation.
#
python - <<CREATEPEM > /tmp/pem.pub

import sys, base64, struct
from pyasn1.type import univ
from pyasn1.codec.der import encoder as der_encoder

keydata = base64.b64decode(
    open("/tmp/ssh.pub").readlines()[0].split()[1])

parts = []
while keydata:
    dlen = struct.unpack('>I', keydata[:4])[0]
    data, keydata = keydata[4:dlen+4], keydata[4+dlen:]
    parts.append(data)

e_val = long(parts[1].encode('hex'), 16)
n_val = long(parts[2].encode('hex'), 16)

pkcs1_seq = univ.Sequence()
pkcs1_seq.setComponentByPosition(0, univ.Integer(n_val))
pkcs1_seq.setComponentByPosition(1, univ.Integer(e_val))
pkcs1_val = der_encoder.encode(pkcs1_seq)

head_seq = univ.Sequence()
head_seq.setComponentByPosition(0, univ.ObjectIdentifier('1.2.840.113549.1.1.1'))
head_seq.setComponentByPosition(1, univ.Null(''))

out_seq = univ.Sequence()
out_seq.setComponentByPosition(0, head_seq)
out_seq.setComponentByPosition(1, univ.BitString("'%s'H" % pkcs1_val.encode('hex')))

print '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----'
print base64.encodestring(der_encoder.encode(out_seq)).strip()
print '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
CREATEPEM

#
# Echo out the script
# That can be used to get the original message
echo
echo
echo "# Execute the following command to decrypt the file"
echo "# It assumes the private version of you key is in ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
echo "# If this is not true the alter to point at the correct file"
echo "#"
echo "# The file has been encrypted using the public key for github user: ${1}"
echo "#"

echo
echo "cat - <<CRYPT | base64 -D | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa "
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey /tmp/pem.pub -ssl -in ${2} | base64
echo "CRYPT"
```

Usage Example:

```
> ./bin/crypt retailcoder T
```

This encrypts the file "T" using the public key of the github user "retailcoder". You know who you are come and see if it works. The output of the above command is:

```
# Execute the following command to decrypt the file
# It assumes the private version of you key is in ~/.ssh/id_rsa
# If this is not true the alter to point at the correct file
#
# The file has been encrypted using the public key for github user: retailcoder
#

cat - <<CRYPT | base64 -D | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa
TyMCN1xl3GIrpYnCdxjYgV/9y5AVyK/G57y952SA6W8/Q9lTxPOIWcsBLO2gvEHM5Df7CFcN/p4n+SxPct2O4AWV0to9+Ch219Bh1+1dy+iYJ8GytrQQx3qC31rpueIt3EIZVwOR0199jGxHViGIJ18tO0A2YHlRIw3DoG7AiJR8zPiTvomvdB2i6EZa+89I/KgK7IL+ADwci50fnnLmGCQ0JR9WbjdkOfeRmYgtO4qFlgBWNdEJFjRhoW6vLjsD7VUE0xcTyK8O01/EPkvhfTroSxRcM5gnIDCOgaRWX7waLwDMkraqeWQjcWIn2n4R6v0Vtk071cAfgfPm7qdvOA==
CRYPT
```

This can be pasted into e-mail or a slack channel. And if you have a terminal cut and pasted to decode.

One more test:

```
> ./bin/crypt Zomis T
```

Please stand up Zomis and tell me it worked :-)

```
# Execute the following command to decrypt the file
# It assumes the private version of you key is in ~/.ssh/id_rsa
# If this is not true the alter to point at the correct file
#
# The file has been encrypted using the public key for github user: Zomis
#

cat - <<CRYPT | base64 -D | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ZXSmyNYaj+t6PO5bQUPSqw+UuvVWKRgUFLMoO015/RspysEaMTz32BlzuMf3DqMXXGdTufrUOGjPjDy07dL4UW2yZ0rVkwEqDJC6Ws1MfwGVwS8XP4n53VgCL/E26GfLRGwaEQGWkcb7/HndwAadzTasu4ZIXEFKWMy4TUb+2/sQDVKArdbv6TrQUgBw6tgPYKZw6jqIpbF+PIrYFYoxS8TXBQkjZw5V2f8/TdQk+qA+xb6aTfaD52ZdDK+UmfkTvZcTTxmGpaHHpAqm40mRTQOcFZvPm1aUoQwq7+zj7LhMXRc2aANVDZxPAR34X56bFcvr/dfSsSNuQ+4pbFshfg==
CRYPT
```

@Mast

A message constructed with your public key `ShipsWithCannons`

```
# Execute the following command to decrypt the file
# It assumes the private version of you key is in ~/.ssh/id_rsa
# If this is not true the alter to point at the correct file
#
# The file has been encrypted using the public key for github user: ShipsWithCannons
#

cat - <<CRYPT | base64 -D | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa
jzBVfg+4QDmfPsSJ4YupIMc5vmY/9Xvo2GH6QIkfrOGQZFZzoKDh7y/4Wl99+P19yf8RGwuhNJPiKRZvtvfPrO1XpXCuYKL9/4guUtYaSea1Bc5itv6Q6n22xLAp+T/d+bOniEO/RjHu6mf1EqoO51vt8YtLHn3PN6xVkzIcsIyOjWlxOu2h+j6HQ+JeIq5yD04hZ7qiiZgNZG3lc7da5cUjOrMdufaG83CApYAt8hYAdU2qWTD+dboVhcIR+JtX5YCO+BayjTwz1a3RLjM8qdiEQu46LLqwfsm6xZU9SGV73KJyON2ju8MBkz0jiXTnzNdTfTfm9V0q6CpoYcWNPg==
CRYPT
```

Comment: What would be the preferred way of testing whether it actually worked? You don't present a decode function, so I assume you tested this in another way.

Comment: @Mast: The output of the script is the decode function. The output can be cut and paste into a bash (or any Linux like) shell and it will decode the message (assuming you have the correct ssh key installed on your machine). I have added a message at the bottom using your public key. You should be able to decode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Hardcoding `/tmp/ssh.pub` in doesn't look right. Makes the script vulnerable to all kinds of failures and race conditions. `tempfile`, perhaps?
- Similar concern applies to `/tmp/pem.pub`. Strongly recommend to derive pem name from `$1`.
- I am not sure I understand the significance of `'1.2.840.113549.1.1.1'`.
- Is there a reason to have a bash/python mixture (vs pure python)?

Comment: The python is to replace `ssh-keygen -f /tmp/ssh.pub -e -m PKCS8` which no longer works on the mac. I don't actually understand the python (nor what `'1.2.840.113549.1.1.1'` means).